# How to use Angular2 canLoadGuard?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I integrated canAuthGuard for each route, but I need to do implement canLoadGuard for access level of each route, how to do this using canLoadGuard?

Comment: your question is confusing and the intention is not clear. Could you post some code clarifying your needs?

Comment: read this docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules